# Files downloaded don't have extension on some devices

Tags: android, file-extension, android-download-manager

I am stuck on a really tricky issue.
Context: My app is built to open files with a special extension (say myFile.png.myapp)

When I download it from my server using Chrome, it downloads fine and I get an "open" prompt and triggers my app, however, the path in the intent is in the form content://downloads/my_downloads/2136.

No extension.

For various reasons, the only MimeType I can send is application/octet-stream, so I have no way of knowing that file is indeed a png.

If I click on the notification that the file is downloaded it works fine.

This only happens for the moment on Nexus 5 running Android 6.0.1, on every other device, I get the actual file name and it's running smoothly.

I have both manifest and in app permissions set up.

My investigation leads me to think it's due to the Helpers class in the DownloadProvider package, but I'm not sure.

Can anyone assist?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up analyzing the headers of the file to extract file signature and determine MimeType. I adapted code found here https://github.com/Muraad/Mime-Detective.

It's not perfect but coherent workaround.

https://github.com/tajoumal/MimeTypeHelper/blob/master/MimeTypeHelper.java

Answer (score 0):

```
String path = "content://downloads/my_downloads/2136";

String mimeType = getContentResolver().getType(Uri.parse(path));
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, the MimeType will always be application/octet-stream so this gives no additional information.

Comment: No. You said `the only MimeType I can send is application/octet-stream`. And sending is something different then determining as is done here. So if Chrome is downloading then what are you sending?

Comment: But you can use DocumentFile for the uri and then DocumentFile.getName() wich gives you the original filename.

Comment: It might have been unclear, but my server is sending the MimeType and it will always be the same. I tried using DocumentFile but alas it gives the same result: In the example, documentFile.getName would be 2136.

Comment: Your server is not sending a file name with it? Which get ignored by Chrome? Dont you see an original file name with the Downloads app?

Comment: My server is, and I see the file name in the Downloads app, but that name is not transmitted to my app when I click on the "open" like shown here:
http://www.androidpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/nexus2cee_header_thumb1.png

Comment: I do nog recognise such an extensive info from a Download app. But i can get the displayname from the content scheme using a CursorLoader with MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME.

Comment: `but my server is sending the MimeType and it will always be the same.`. You are still confusing. That mime type is pretty irrelevant as here we are talking about a mime type of a file served by the Downloads app. Your servers mime type has long been forgotton by that time.

Comment: Maybe this will clarify a bit more. I do not download using my app, I download it from a webpage (where I set the MimeType of the file that will be downloaded), hosted on my server, using a browser on a device.

The browser downloads it fine, and then shows a popup. When clicked, that popup sends out an intent which launches my app. 

When I receive the intent in my app, it contains only two elements: the path (which doesn't contain the file name) and the MimeType (which is a hardcoded mimetype so it doesn't help me identify the file type)

Comment: Also, I'm working with multiple data types, it can be png, pdf, audio, etc.

Comment: Did you try with the CursorLoader and so? It would be nice if you tried or at least commented on it.

Comment: It did not work, I got an NPE. Thanks for assisting.